# How come shell script in Jenkins pipeline does not see local variable?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run the following shell script in my Jenkins pipeline.

```
      sshagent(credentials: ['myBBCreds']) {
        sh(label: "Commit updated translation files",
           script: """
             DIFF=`git diff --name-only`
             if [ ! -z "$DIFF" ]; then
               echo "We have diffs: $DIFF"
               git add .
               git commit . -m "Jenkins ($environment - Zift123): Automated check-in of i18n files"            
             fi
           """,
           returnStatus: true)
      }
```

But I get the following error in my console

```
ERROR: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: DIFF for class: WorkflowScript
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: You are resolving shell interpreter variables within the string interpolation of the Groovy interpreter with this syntax. What language variable is `$environment`?

Comment: you just need to escape the `$DIFF` as `\$DIFF`, otherwise string interpolation will consider it as environment variable instead of local script variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [String Iterpolation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation) in the Jenkins Pipeline documentation.

Since a Groovy triple double-quoted string is used to pass the shell script to the `sh` step, the string is first processed by Groovy trying to replace the `$DIFF` with a Pipeline variable. Since `DIFF` is a shell variable unavailable in the Groovy context, you get the error.

A triple single quoted string should resolve the issue. e.g.:

```
sh(label: "Commit updated translation files",
   script: '''
     DIFF=`git diff --name-only`
     if [ ! -z "$DIFF" ]; then
       echo "We have diffs: $DIFF"
       git add .
       git commit . -m "Jenkins ($environment - Zift123): Automated check-in of i18n files"            
     fi
   ''',
   returnStatus: true)
```

There might be an issue with `$environment` if it is not a simple string variable that is part of `env`.